# Phalcon-compose & Docker Toolbox web-server sees no files

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phalcon

My OS is Windows 7 and I'm using Docker Toolbox. I was following [this](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.2/environments-docker) tutorial, but then I got stuck when trying to open the web-page because my browser said it couldn't establish a connection.

variables.env (the rest is default):

```
# Application
WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/project/public
WEB_ALIAS_DOMAIN=localhost
APPLICATION_CACHE=/project/cache
APPLICATION_LOGS=/project/logs
# production | development | staging | testing
APPLICATION_ENV=development
```

hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Then I found that there's a program called Kitematic that had been installed with Docker Tools so I opened it and saw all of my containers. I went to "wildlife_app_1" which is my web-server and saw a console with a warning in it:

```
[WARNING] WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT does not exists with path "/project/public"!
```

There was a button called "exec" which allows to open a container's terminal so I opened it and I found that there actually wasn't such a directory as "public" in "/project".

Does anyone know how to fix that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is rather a workaround than a solution, but anyway. I've changed the "." dots in the config file with the absolute path to the project directory from.

Before:

```
  - ./application:/project
  - ./cache:/project/cache
  - ./logs:/project/logs
```

After:

```
  - C:/Users/Dmitriy/Desktop/projects/Wildlife/application:/project
  - C:/Users/Dmitriy/Desktop/projects/Wildlife/cache:/project/cache
  - C:/Users/Dmitriy/Desktop/projects/Wildlife/logs:/project/logs
```

And it works now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your host (local machine IP) in the `hosts` file eg. `192.168.1.129`. Note: here the `192.168.1.129` IP address just for example.

You can often find the information quickly using the Command Prompt or Terminal. In Windows, you can open the Start menu, search for Command Prompt, and press Enter. Then type `ipconfig` in the Command Prompt that appears and press Enter—you’ll get to what you’re looking for in no time.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, Kitematic says that the web-site is located at http://192.168.99.100/ as well. Now the problem is that files and directories aren't copied from my project's folder to the container's so the server can find them and work.

Comment: Try to start app without Kitematic by using `docker-compose up ...`

Comment: I don't start my app with Kitematic, I start with "docker-compose up -d" as it was written in the manual I had followed.